# Unable to align image buttons inside relative and linear layout

Tags: android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout

I want to have 3 image buttons in first row and 3 image buttons in second row.
I tried implementing it with a combination of relative and linear layout but, somehow I am ending up with 1 image button in each row, and total of 6 rows.

Can someone please help me in aligning the 3 image boxes in first row and 3 boxes in second row.

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="app.com.date.design.drawer.AddImagesFragment">

    <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/layout1"
            android:baselineAligned="false"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/common_full_open_on_phone"
                android:id="@+id/image1" />

            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/common_full_open_on_phone"
                android:id="@+id/image2" />

            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/common_full_open_on_phone"
                android:id="@+id/image3" />

            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/common_full_open_on_phone"
                android:id="@+id/image4" />

            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/common_full_open_on_phone"
                android:id="@+id/image5" />

            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/common_full_open_on_phone"
                android:id="@+id/image6"
                android:layout_weight="0.05" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This Code,

**activity_main.xml :**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/lin1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="3">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/image1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/star2" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/image2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/star1" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/image3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/star3" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/lin2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/lin1"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="3">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/image4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/star2" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/image5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/star1" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/image6"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/star3" />

    </LinearLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Hereby, i m attaching Screenshot,

[image]

Hope it will help you.